# Access denied to most features in Google Cloud official app, why?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I installed the official app ***Google Cloud*** to manage and monitor my *Google Cloud* ressources. I then logged in using an account with an `Owner` role on the top structure *My Organization* and an `Owner` role on all its sub-projects as well. I am `super-admin` in *Google Workspace*.

However, I can't seem to access/list any project or ressource in the app. Basically it tells me I lack permissions.

I tried looking for specific ***IAM*** permissions for this scenario but without luck.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

In Google Workspace Admin console, you must activate the service named **Additional services without individual control**.

`Menu 'Apps' > 'Additional Google services' > 'CHANGE' next to 'Access to additional services without individual control for all organisational units is turned Off' (info icon in the upper zone) > 'ON for everyone'`

Answer (score 1):

To get the permissions that you need to manage access to a project, folder, or organization in Google official cloud  you need to have following IAM roles on the resource that you want to manage access for (project, folder, or organization):

- To manage access to a project: Project IAM Admin
  (roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin)
- To manage access to a folder: Folder Admin
  (roles/resourcemanager.folderAdmin)
- To manage access to projects, folders, and organizations:
  Organization Admin (roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin)
- To manage access to almost all Google Cloud resources: Security Admin
  (roles/iam.securityAdmin)

For more information about granting roles, see [Required permissions and Manage access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) and check these [roles](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#basic_roles).

Comment: I tried adding all these permissions (most of them were already there). Doesn't change a thing. I'm wondering if it's not a bug maybe? I sent a message to the support from inside the app.

Comment: Have you received any response? If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Unfortunately had not received any response yet. I will keep you updated of course.

Comment: @Kay have you managed to make this google cloud app works properly ? i'm encountering the same issues while owner of the project ..

Comment: @f1rstsurf No! I’m still looking for a solution. I’m really starting to think it’s a bug though.

Comment: @Kay just to let you know that everything is now working fine. I can access all datas from the app !

Comment: @f1rstsurf No change on my side yet.

Comment: Not pretty sure if it can helps, but 2 weeks ago I’ve reported the issue on the app using the « send feedback » function, located under the bubble button.

Comment: I did as well...

Comment: @Kay If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: @HemanthKumar Unfortunately no solution for me yet.

Comment: It suddenly works! A setting in my Google Workspace might be responsible for this. I have to make a few tests and will post a response with the results right after.

Comment: @HemanthKumar I provided the solution in a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996119/16799703